# specify the specific x ticks label

Tags: plotting

```
N0 = 10000;
N1 = N0/4;

s = 0.001; 
T = 500;
N0 = 10000;
N1 = 5000;
t0 = 0;
NtStep[t_, T_] := Piecewise[{{N0, t <= T}}, N1]
   Tvalues = Range[0, N0/2, N0/100];

(*Pfix= 1. - Exp[-1/\!\(
 \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(Infinity\)]\(
 \*SuperscriptBox[\(\[ExponentialE]\), \(\(-s\)\ t\)]\ 
 \*FractionBox[\(N0\), \(Nt[t]\)]\[DifferentialD]t\)\)]*)

    Pfix[T_] := 
 1. - Exp[-4/
  NIntegrate[
   E^(-s (t - t0)) (2 NtStep[t0, T])/NtStep[t, T], {t, t0, 10000}]]
   pfixvalues = Pfix /@ Tvalues;

 w0[T_] := N0 (1 - 1/(2 N1))^(10000 - T);
w1[T_] :=  N1 (1 - Exp[-(10000 - T)/(2 N1)]);
 Neff[T_] := (N0 w0 [T] + N1  w1[T])/(w0 [T] + w1[T]);

 PfixNeff[T_] :=  (1 - Exp[-2 s])/(1 - Exp[-2 Neff[T] s]) ;
 Pfixotto[T_] := 2/(
  NtStep[t0, T]  NIntegrate[ 
  E^(- s (t - t0)) 1/NtStep[t, T], {t, t0, 10000}])
 pfixvaluesotto = Pfixotto /@ Tvalues;
 pfixneff = PfixNeff /@ Tvalues;

 customTicksX = Table[{i N0/140, Row[{"N0/", i}]}, {i, 0, N0/2, 1}];

     a = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose@{Tvalues, pfixvalues}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
    Ticks -> {customTicksX, Automatic}];

 b = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose@{Tvalues, pfixvaluesotto}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"T", "pfix"}, 
   Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
   Frame -> Thickness[0.003], Ticks -> {customTicksX, Automatic}];

 c = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose@{Tvalues, pfixneff}, 
     PlotStyle -> Magenta, PlotRange -> All, 
     FrameLabel -> {"T", "pfix"}, Frame -> True, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
      Frame -> Thickness[0.003], Ticks -> {customTicksX, Automatic}];

  Show[b, a, c, PlotRange -> All]
```

It generates the x axis ticks automatically and the number appeared are 100, 500, 1000, 5000. I want them to appear as N0/100, N0/20, N0/10, N0/2